# jQuery Gradual Sink Effect Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

There are two ways to do this the way I see it without flash.

When you move your mouse over the image; it gradually changes to the hover class. Or when when you hover over the image, the margins change each side going either horizontal either way.

The first way would be better but it is CSS at the end of the day. I want this button to gradually sink when you hover over it - and you move your mouse off, it bounces back:

## Html

```
<center><br /><br />
<a href="#"><img src="//gc-cdn.com/button.png" alt=""></a>
</center>
```

## Css

```
img{border-right:15px solid #333;border-bottom:15px solid #333}
img:hover{border-right:1px solid #333;border-bottom:1px solid #333}
```

## jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/fk6eG/9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need javascript to do this, you can use CSS transitions:

```
img{
    border-right:15px solid #333;
    border-bottom:15px solid #333;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
img:hover{border-right:1px solid #333;border-bottom:1px solid #333}​
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fk6eG/15/

Edit: For a jquery solution, you could use the jquery UI [switch class](http://jqueryui.com/docs/switchClass/) method:

CSS:

```
 .c1{border-right:15px solid #333;border-bottom:15px solid #333;}
 .c2{border-right:1px solid #333;border-bottom:1px solid #333}​
```

Javascript:

```
$(".c1").hover(function () {
        $(this).switchClass("c1", "c2", 1000);        
    }, function () {
        $(this).switchClass("c2", "c1", 1000);    
    });​
```

Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fk6eG/23/

Comment: Very interesting. Could you please post a jQuery solution to and will mark as answered. Where can I see more in those as reference?

Comment: Dare I say this - not all browsers support transition elements.

Comment: See the updated answer. The jquery version does appear to work in IE8, but the CSS version does not.

Comment: @DavidThomas the CSS transition will work in Chrome, FX, and IE9+. For the rest of the world still on IE6-8 the jQuery `switchClass` will work better, but be careful with IE6 as it leaks memory with jQuery.